# Can't write "}" with my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, visual-studio

I got a problem with my Visual Studio.
I can't write the sign "{"..

My keyboard got the "QWERTY" layout, the Swedish one.

Comment: Have you checked the keyboard layout?

Comment: I'm able to write "}" with this: ALT-GR+0  But I want to use CTRL+ALT+0

Comment: Does the symbol display in Notepad / Word / similar?

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is in Visual Basic..

Comment: Help me please :)